# Equation number bigger than 10 in appendices do not get the cross-reference

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, appendices

I have encountered a funny problem with my equations (in appendix) cross-referencing. If, in appendices, I have equations more than ten (for example A.10, A.11, B.13) when I click on the cross-reference link, (I use `\autoref` ) it jumps to the equation with the same number in the body text (for example 10, 11, 13) not the equation in appendix. I wonder if you have faced this problem before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{empheq}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue}

\begin{document}

    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{30pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{30pt}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{30pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{30pt}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:2}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:3}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:4}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:5}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:6}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:7}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:8}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:9}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:10}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:11}
F=ma
\end{equation}


\autoref{eq:10}
\autoref{eq:A10}
\autoref{eq:B10}




\newpage
\begin{appendices}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}


%######################################################################
\section{Fist Appendix} \label{app:A}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A1}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A2}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A3}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A4}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A5}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A6}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A7}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A8}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A9}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A10}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}

    text
    text\\
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:A11}
    F=ma
    \end{equation}






%###################################################################### 
\newpage
\section{Second Appendix} \label{app:B}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B1}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B2}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B3}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B4}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B5}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B6}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B7}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B8}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B9}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B10}
F=ma
\end{equation}

text
text\\
\begin{equation} \label{eq:B11}
F=ma
\end{equation}



\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal document that shows the problem. Not your actual document, but one that shows the problem and what class and cross-referencing package you are using.

Comment: Sorry I did not post my code because the number of equations more than 10 for a body and two appendices would make it long and space-consuming. Now I do.

Comment: You don't need to post all the code, you can just increment the equation counter and have one or two equations.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem under your current minimal example. Clicking on the respective `\autoref` links takes me directly to three *separate* locations: Equations (10) on p 2, (A.10) on p 4, and (B.10) on p 6.

Comment: `\cleveref` should come as the last package here, just after `hyperref`

Comment: @Werner You are right, it does work for this sample, I do not know why but it does not work out for my report. I am trying to find a resolution. Do I need to remove the posted code?

Comment: @Reza: If there's an error in your report, make a copy of your report document and try to reduce it step by step until the error vanishes. You'll most likely figure out where the error(s) could be.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did! once I reach the equation number 10 the problem pops up! It has been one day I am playing a game with it, I will post my edit as soon as I find the defect.

Comment: Those `\\ ` before your equations are very wrong, you should delete them (although unrelated to your cross reference question) Also it is very confusing to use numbers in `\label{.}` as the numbers are unrelated to the equation number.

Comment: I just removed the package usage of `cleverer` from the preamble and it worked!

Comment: @Reza: I am wondering about this 'solution'.